# Why does this library refrain from using static_cast?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, armadillo, static-cast

I try to follow the mantra of "no warnings." I try to write my code so that the compiler gives no warnings. I'm starting to use non-standard libraries for the first time.

I recently installed mlpack (with armadillo) using

```
vcpkg install mlpack:x64-windows
```

I built the library and it works. However, my compiler gives loads of warnings. These warnings seem like they could have been fixed by the developer, but I'm not sure.

Many of the warnings are about conversions. For example, the first such compiler warning is

```
'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'const arma::arma_rng::seed_type', possible loss of data
```

This occurs in the line

```
arma::arma_rng::set_seed(seed);
```

where `seed` is always of type `const size_t`. I made the following change:

```
arma::arma_rng::set_seed(static_cast<arma::arma_rng::seed_type>(seed));
```

This removed the warning. Another fix is to overload `arma::arma_rng::set_seed` to take a double and perform the conversion within the function.

Given that the armadillo library is so popular, I assume someone at some point would have recommended these changes. Is there a reason not to add `static_cast` here (i.e., is this an optimization)?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend passing seeds around as floating point types. Random generation is sensitive to distribution statistics, and `double`'s loss of precision might significantly degrade the quality of the RNG. It may also break the repeatability of previously obtained values (such as for unit tests).

Comment: Whether you `static_cast` or not, the value will be converted. Adding the cast just acknowleges to the compiler that the conversion is expected and intentional, and that it is not an oversight.

Comment: you are merely silencing the warning while the code has the same issue as without the static cast.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This one library gives 16 warnings, 12 of which are conversion warnings that would disappear with ```static_cast``` and 2 of which are ```<``` signed/unsigned mismatch warnings. Adding ```static_cast``` would remove the warnings.

Comment: you know about `-isystem` ? Should be used with care, but if the library is reliable it can be very useful to build with warnings enabled and see only warnings in your code

Comment: @user589321 `static_cast` silences the warning. The warnings have merit, the implicit conversions can introduce subtle bugs. Only add the `static_cast` if you've inspected the site of the conversion and can confirm beyond doubt that there is no such bug.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks for the recommendation. I am using Visual Studio, but it seems that VS has an equivalent thing with ```\external```. Got it working with no warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have the library available, so I'll use a different example. Consider the following code is in the library. Its a completely made up example, but I hope it resembles the situation more or less:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(unsigned char x) {
    std::cout << (int)x << "\n";
}

void bar_warn(int a){
    foo(a);
}

void bar_no_warn(int a){
    foo(static_cast<unsigned char>(a));
}
```

gcc warns for `bar_warn` but not for `bar_no_warn`:

```
<source>:4:9: error: conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char' may change value [-Werror=conversion]
    4 |     foo(a);
      |         ^
```

The `std::cout << (int)x` is just to see the effect of following user code:

```
int main() {
    bar_warn(123456);
    bar_no_warn(123456);
}
```

Output is

```
64
64
```

That is: The user code is completely fine. It has no errors nor does it trigger warnings. The issue is in the library code. The cast does change the value. And that is the case with or without the static cast. The static cast does not "fix" the cast in any way, it merely silences the warning.

If you can browse all usages of the cast and make sure that the reason for the warning never takes place then you can use a `static_cast` to silence the warning. In library code that is not always possible. The library cannot foresee all usages. User code might pass a value that is too big and a user might get unexpected results. In such case it is better for the library to warn rather than to silence the warning.

If you are bothered by the warning you can still silence it. For example gcc has `-isystem` to not output warnings in system headers. I suppose other compilers have similar option.